# Overconstrained planning with initializing score trend

Tags: java, optaplanner, timefold

I am using optaplanner and have a nullable planning variable. HardMediumSoftLongScore. **Tasks** are the planning entities and **timeslots** are the planning values. We want to allow tasks to remain with a null timeslot, but prefer they didn't.

What I've noticed, although I don't remember if this has always been the case, is that the construction phase never gives a score update. Even in the case where every Planning Entity is assigned a value (that is not null).

So I really have two questions.

1. Is it intended that construction phases don't dispatch score updates?
2. I'm guessing this is unrelated to #1. but I'm curious nonetheless. Can/should a initializing score trend be set with an over-constrained problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Construction Heuristics only gives an event at the end of the CH (to avoid the performance overhead of cloning the working solution for every step).

That being said, there was [a bug with that](https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-solver/issues/25), fixed in Timefold 0.9.39 and 0.8.39.

Comment: Migrated to timefold, which was a breeze, and CH now dispatch score updates. Thanks for the insight!